# Select value after blur with bootstrap typeahead

Tags: javascript, focus, blur, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I'm looking for a way to select a value on blur. After typing in my search and clicking outside of the input box (input box loses focus), even though the suggestion I typed is a valid value, the select event doesn't work. If I don't manually click on the value from the dropdown, hit tab or hit enter, the value from the dropdown doesn't get selected (those three seem to be the only way to trigger select).I would like the first option from my dropdown to be selected when I blur or lose focus from my input box. Is there a way I can achieve this? Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

I've seen this question asked and answered with angular typeahead but I am looking to solve this with bootstrap typeahead.

I'm using bootstrap typeahead v2.3.2